# Jenkins Artifactory plugin - upload from shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I've using Jenkins Artifactory plugin from a scripted pipeline to upload artifacts to the Artifactory. The pipeline code was this:

```
def uploadSpec = ...
def artifactory = Artifactory.server 'myTag'
def buildInfo = server.upload(JsonOutput.toJson(uploadSpec))
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

This has been working well, however this, among a lot of other code, has been duplicated in multiple projects.  I am now extracting all common code and putting it into a Jenkins Shared Library. I got everything else to work, however I'm struggling to get the artifactory bit working.  I've tried all sorts of things with different errors.  My last attempt was this:

```
def server = getArtifactoryServer serverTag
server.upload(JsonOutput.toJson(myUploadSpec))
```

This results in a `NullPointerException`, which I traced (in the plugin source code) to `cpsScript` variable, which is not set.  I tried using the `upload` step as defined [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/#artifactoryupload-upload-artifacts):

```
def buildInfo = artifactoryUpload(
        spec: myUploadSpec,
        buildInfo: new BuildInfo(),
        module: null,
        failNoOp: false,
        server: server
)
```

Yet, this results in a different error:

```
 WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.UploadStep': module
 org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.String
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.loadConstructorParamNames(ClassDescriptor.java:265)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.<init>(DescribableModel.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:474)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:269)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
 Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {spec={files=[{pattern=Vertx365/Production/build/vertx365-production-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertx365/vertx365-production/3.37.0/}, {pattern=Vertx365/QA/build/vertx365-qa-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertx365/vertx365-qa/3.37.0/}, {pattern=VertxBCSS/Production/build/vertxbcss-production-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertxbcss/vertxbcss-production/3.37.0/}, {pattern=VertxBCSS/QA/build/vertxbcss-qa-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertxbcss/vertxbcss-qa/3.37.0/}, {pattern=VertxBIM/Production/build/vertxbim-production-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertxbim/vertxbim-production/3.37.0/}, {pattern=VertxBIM/QA/build/vertxbim-qa-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertxbim/vertxbim-qa/3.37.0/}, {pattern=VertxCatering/QA/build/vertxcatering-qa-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertxcatering/vertxcatering-qa/3.37.0/}, {pattern=VertxLockhart/Production/build/vertxlockhart-production-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertxlockhart/vertxlockhart-production/3.37.0/}, {pattern=VertxLockhart/QA/build/vertxlockhart-qa-3.37.0.zip, target=vertx-release/com/bunzl/vertx/release/vertxlockhart/vertxlockhart-qa/3.37.0/}]}, buildInfo=org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.buildInfo.BuildInfo@caaf82, failNoOp=false, module=null, server=org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.types.ArtifactoryServer@1e1cacd} for org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.UploadStep
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:269)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at com.bunzl.pipeline.artifactory.Artifactory.uploadFiles(Artifactory.groovy:10)
    at com.bunzl.pipeline.artifactory.Artifactory.uploadFiles(Artifactory.groovy)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:117)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Of course, I can retrieve the `ArtifactoryServer` object in the main pipeline and then pass it into the shared library call, but that's a wrong design.

So, how can I achieve what I need (i.e.upload artifacts to a server with specified tag) inside a shared library?

Any idea on how I can get this working?

**EDIT:** Per request in a comment, I have this structure (for the class calling artifactory):

```
+
|
+- src
    |
    +- com
        |
        +- mycompany
            |
            +- mypackage
                |
                +- Artifactory.groovy
```

Here's the code in this class (with private/proprietary bits replace):

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage

import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def uploadFiles(String serverTag, List files, boolean buildInfoPublish = true) {
    def server = getArtifactoryServer serverTag
    def buildInfo = server.upload(JsonOutput.toJson([files: files]))

    if (buildInfoPublish) {
        publishBuildInfo buildInfo: buildInfo, server: server
    }
}
```

The library is defined in Jenkins as a global library named `config-library` and is being used/called like this:

```
def configLibrary = library('config-library@my-version')
def artifactory = configLibrary.com.mycompany.mypackage.Artifactory.new()
def files = ...
artifactory.uploadFiles('myTag', files)
```

Comment: Please add how your shared library code is organized. Is it a script in `vars\ `, a class in `src\ `, etc.? How are you calling it from the main pipeline script?

Comment: @zett42 I've add all the info

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using? The 'module' parameter was only introduced in 3.6.1, so using an earlier version might be causing the "unknown parameter 'module'" error you are seeing. Can't say for sure as I haven't tried this approach myself

Comment: @Prostagma I tried removing `module` parameter completely - same error - `There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class java.lang.String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out after debugging a local installation of the plugin.  Apparently, `artifactoryUpload` expects the `spec` parameter to be a JSON string, not an object.  So, the solution is quite simple:

```
def server = getArtifactoryServer serverTag
def buildInfo = artifactoryUpload(
        spec: JsonOutput.toJson(myUploadSpec),
        buildInfo: new BuildInfo(),
        module: null,
        failNoOp: false,
        server: server
)
```